# App stoped working when navigation.navigate in createSwitchNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have some code to navigate to the login screen when the user selects Logout in the main screen. Unfortunately, the app stopped working when navigating to the Login screen.  By that I mean, the app closes with a dialog box and the app is stopped.

What is wrong in my code?

This my `SwitchNavigator`:

```
const AppSwitchNavigator = createAnimatedSwitchNavigator({
    SplashScreen: {
        screen: screenSplash
    },
    LoginScreen: {
        screen: screenLogin
    },
    MainScreen: {
        screen: AppTab
    }
}, {
        initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',
        transition: (
            <Transition.Together>
                <Transition.Out
                    type="slide-bottom"
                    durationMs={400}
                    interpolation="easeIn"
                />
                <Transition.In type="fade" durationMs={500} />
            </Transition.Together>
        ),
    });
```

This function is called when the user logs out:

```
async logoutProses() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        await firebase.auth().signOut()
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("userData")
        await GoogleSignin.signOut()
        this.setState({ isLoading: false })
        this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")
}
```

error information in console debug:

```
Error: No user currently signed in.
    at createErrorFromErrorData (fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2108)
    at fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2060
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2627)
    at fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2358
    at MessageQueue.__guard (fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2531)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2357)
    at e (RNDebuggerWorker.js:1)
reactConsoleErrorHandler @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:22755
console.error @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:67435
logoutProses$ @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:205207
tryCatch @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:23070
invoke @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:23245
prototype.(anonymous function) @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:23113
tryCatch @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:23070
invoke @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:23146
(anonymous) @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:23158
tryCallOne @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:24362
(anonymous) @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:24463
(anonymous) @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:27856
_callTimer @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:27745
_callImmediatesPass @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:27781
callImmediates @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:28000
__callImmediates @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2548
(anonymous) @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2369
__guard @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2531
flushedQueue @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2368
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue @ fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:2361
e @ RNDebuggerWorker.js:1
fb338eb7-b190-4075-a4c6-86ad832e0cdb:22755 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in AkunScreen (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at react-navigation-collapsible/index.js:302)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at react-navigation-collapsible/index.js:301)
    in _withCollapsible (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:888)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:887)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at StackViewLayout.tsx:886)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:61)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:80)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:971)
    in RNSScreenContainer (at screens.native.js:85)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:383)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:379)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:372)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:103)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:40)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:61)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at createTabNavigator.js:39)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at BottomNavigation.js:646)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at BottomNavigation.js:631)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at BottomNavigation.js:615)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at BottomNavigation.js:611)
    in BottomNavigation (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ThemeProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in withTheme(BottomNavigation) (at createMaterialBottomTabNavigator.js:51)
    in BottomNavigationView (at createTabNavigator.js:197)
    in NavigationView (at createNavigator.js:61)
    in Navigator (at SceneView.js:9)
```

Comment: `Unfortunately App is stoped working` what do you mean by stoped working? You got an error? The functionality stopped? It freezed? Please be more clear on the problem

Comment: Turn on Remote JS Debugging, and edit your question with its output when the crash happens. Without that output we cant really help you solve your problem.